# Why isn't opencover writing to the specified output file?

Tags: .net, nunit, code-coverage, opencover

I'm running OpenCover with the following command line (wrapped for clarity) from an Admin Console.

> packages\OpenCover.1.0.625\OpenCover.Console.exe -register:user 
>       -target:packages\NUnit.2.5.10.11092\tools\nunit-console.exe 
>       -targetargs:"FooProject.nunit" 
>       -filter:+[*]* -output:coverage.xml

I get the output below but the specified coverage.xml file is not create.

**Why isn't the output file created?**

**update**
I have registered both the 32 and 64 bit profilers as suggested in [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999279/opencover-msbuild-integration-no-results-generated) and removed the `-register` flag, but I still get the same output

> NUnit version 2.5.10.11092
>   Copyright (C) 2002-2009 Charlie Poole.
>   Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.
>   Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
>   All Rights Reserved.
>
> Runtime Environment -
>      OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
>     CLR Version: 2.0.50727.5446 ( Net 2.0 )
>
> ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Default
>   Execution Runtime: Default
>   ..................F....F.F.............F............F..F..F......
>   Tests run: 58, Errors: 0, Failures: 7, Inconclusive: 0, Time: 1.5298027 seconds
>     Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Skipped: 0
>
> Errors and Failures:
>   1) Test Failure : FooProject.Tests.Controllers.BarControllerTests.Index
>   at FooProject.Tests.Controllers.BarControllerTests.Index() in C:\FooProject\FooProject.Tests\Controllers\BarControllerTests.cs:line 27
>
> 2) Test Failure : FooProject.Tests.Controllers.FringControllerTests.Index
>   at FooProject.Tests.Controllers.FringControllerTests.Index() in C:\FooProject\FooProject.Tests\Controllers\FringControllerTests.cs:line 107
>
> 3) Test Failure : FooProject.Tests.Controllers.FringControllerTests.Save
>   at FooProject.Tests.Controllers.FringControllerTests.Save() in C:\FooProject\FooProject.Tests\Controllers\FringControllerTests.cs:line 135
>
> 4) Test Failure : FooProject.Tests.Repositories.FringRepositoryTests.Foo
>   at FooProject.Tests.Repositories.FringRepositoryTests.Foo() in C:\FooProject\FooProject.Tests\Repositories\FringRepositoryTests.cs:line 17
>
> 5) Test Failure : FooProject.Tests.Services.BarServiceTests.Frob
>   at FooProject.Tests.Services.BarServiceTests.Frob() in C:\FooProject\FooProject.Tests\Services\BarServiceTests.cs:line 52
>
> 6) Test Failure : FooProject.Tests.Services.FringServiceTests.Frob
>   at FooProject.Tests.Services.FringServiceTests.Frob() in C:\FooProject\FooProject.Tests\Services\FringServiceTests.cs:line 39
>
> 7) Test Failure : FooProject.Tests.Services.FringServiceTests.Frob
>   at FooProject.Tests.Services.FringServiceTests.Frob() in C:\FooProject\FooProject.Tests\Services\FringServiceTests.cs:line 139
>
> Committing....

Answer (score 2):

It is probably because the profiler hasn't instrumented any assemblies due to missing PDBs.

OpenCover only profiles assemblies for which the PDBs exist.

Nunit copies the assemblies but not the PDBs to an alternate location before testing. Try using the **/noshadow** option.

NOTE: you may also wish to avoid the **+[***]*** option as this will mean that you may get instrumentation of all assemblies that you have PDBs i.e. Test assemblies as well as target assemblies and other 3rd party assemblies - this will cause the testing to be slow.

---

28 Aug 2011 - I have just tested this with the opencover tests and an .nunit file will do shadow copy and so no PDB files found - however if I **-targetargs:"OpenCover.Test.nunit /noshadow"** then the tests run as expected.

Also make sure the default configuration in the .nunit file has all your tests in it.

Comment: Got it working but not had time to diagnose the exact issue. Will update later. Cheers